# Nginx returns 404 error for some angularJS URLs for sometime

Tags: angularjs, nginx, http-status-code-404, varnish, prerender

I am using Nginx Server for surfing AngularJS based website (with HTML mode True to avoid # in URLs). Apart from this I have configured Varnish to reduce load on server. So Varnish runs on port 80 and Nginx runs on port 81. I am using prerender.io for SEO of AngularJS website.

The problem is, when prerender tries to recache the angular URLs, Nginx returns 404 error code.

My nginx.conf is as follow:

```
    server {
    listen       81 default_server;
    listen       [::]:81 default_server;
    server_name  abcxyzabc.com;
    root         /var/www/html/abcxyzabc/;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Prerender-Token ****************;     

        set $prerender 0;
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "baiduspider|twitterbot|facebookexternalhit|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|quora link preview|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest|slackbot|vkShare|W3C_Validator") {
            set $prerender 1;
        }
        if ($args ~ "_escaped_fragment_") {
            set $prerender 1;
        }
        if ($http_user_agent ~ "Prerender") {
            set $prerender 0;
        }
        if ($uri ~* "\.(js|css|xml|less|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|pdf|doc|txt|ico|rss|zip|mp3|rar|exe|wmv|doc|avi|ppt|mpg|mpeg|tif|wav|mov|psd|ai|xls|mp4|m4a|swf|dat|dmg|iso|flv|m4v|torrent|ttf|woff|svg|eot)") {
            set $prerender 0;
        }

        #resolve using Google's DNS server to force DNS resolution and prevent caching of IPs
        resolver 8.8.8.8;

        if ($prerender = 1) {

            #setting prerender as a variable forces DNS resolution since nginx caches IPs and doesnt play well with load balancing
            set $prerender "service.prerender.io";
            rewrite .* /$scheme://$host$request_uri? break;
            proxy_pass http://$prerender;
        }

        location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
            expires 30d;
        }

        location /status {
            # Turn on nginx stats
            stub_status on;
            # I do not need logs for stats
            access_log   off;
            # Security: Only allow access from localhost IP #
            allow 127.0.0.1;
            # Send rest of the world to /dev/null #
            deny all;
        }

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

        gzip_vary on;
        gzip_proxied any;
        gzip_comp_level 6;
        gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        gzip_http_version 1.1;
        gzip_min_length 256;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf font/opentype image/svg+xml image/x-icon;

        error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
        }

        location ~ /\. {
            deny  all;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen 81;
        server_name www.xyzabcxyz.com;
        return 301 $scheme://xyzabcxyz.com$request_uri;
        proxy_set_header X-Prerender-Token ***************;
    }
```

With the above nginx configuration file, when prerender tries to recache the URLs, Nginx returns 404 error page. And after some time the same URL works fine. This case introduced after inserting prerender code in nginx configuration. Before the everything was good. Please help me out. Any solution/suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: It may help https://superuser.com/questions/916684/nginx-serving-angularjs-app-returns-404-not-found